# how to disable tooltip for jqueryui

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I want to use jquery tooltip from jquery js but not from jquery-ui.js and I want progress bar in modal using jquery-ui. But when I include jquery-ui.js in jsp page the tooltip is showing from jquery-ui only not from jquery-min.js. Below is my code could you please help me?

```
<link href="<%=context%>/resources/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="<%=context%>/resources/bootstrap/bootstrap-theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="<%=context%>/scripts/jqueryui/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/scripts/jqueryui/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="<%=context%>/resources/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/scripts/jqueryui/jquery.fileDownload.js"></script>
<script src="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/scripts/jqueryui/jquery-ui.js">  </script>

<div class="source">
    <div id="preparing-file-modal" title="Preparing report..." style="display: none;">
        We are preparing your report, please wait...
        <div class="ui-progressbar-value ui-corner-left ui-corner-right"
                style="width: 100%; height: 22px; margin-top: 20px;">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="error-modal" title="Error" style="display: none;">
            There was a problem generating your report, please try again. 
    </div>
</div>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();  
    $(document).on("click","a.downloadCsr",function(){
        var preparingFileModal = $("#preparing-file-modal");
        $(preparingFileModal).dialog({ modal: true });
        return false;
    }); 
});
</script>

<style>
.ui-progressbar-value { 
    background-image: url(<%=context%>/images/pbar-ani.gif); 
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

By far simplest for you is to only bundle the library parts of jQuery UI which you need.

http://jqueryui.com/download/

Simply deselect Tooltip from that bundle, and you should be good to go.